# add alpn-boot jar to bootclasspath

Tags: java, alpn, bootclasspath

Working with our dev team to get apple push notifications working and I need some help getting a jar into the java bootclass path. We are running RHEL 6.9 and java8.

when I try to do the normal: java -Xbootclasspath/p:/opt/batch/lib/pathtojar.jar I dont seem to be getting any confirmation nor errors. simply prints our the java help page.

I've also confirmed we are using the correct alpn-boot jar for our java version. I'm probably just running into a wall I cant see at the moment, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

answer to problem:

the script we run for this job is not continuous, therefore I simply had to add the -Xbootclasspath/p:/opt/batch/lib/pathtojar.jar to the calls in the script. whereas i thought the command was supposed to be passed to change a value to a configuration file.

simply me misunderstanding something I had never done before.

Comment: please explain your answer? I'm stuck with the same problem. What do you mean by "I simply had to add the -Xbootclasspath/p:/opt/batch/lib/pathtojar.jar to the calls in the script"?